# Support for Multidimensional Scaling (MDS)?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, packages

Does *Mathematica* support MDS? Or, are there any libraries that support it?

Basically, I have points and a distance function defined between them, and I want to plot them in 2D space, trying to minimize the error (stress) in the distance. This is what MDS does. R has [support for MDS](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/mds.html), but I can't find similar methods in *Mathematica*, which I think is strange because this seems like a really common thing to want to do...

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no built-in functionality for this.  [Google revealed a package to do this](http://www.skidmore.edu/~flip/Site/Downloads/Entries/2007/6/21_MDS_for_Mathematica_6.0.html), but I have not used it myself.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the answer to the question.

Comment: Did you try the package?  Does it work correctly with version 8?

Comment: @Sz [Graph embedding](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GraphDrawingIntroduction.html) in two dimensions is actually MDS in disguise.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about that. But, there does not seem to be a way to change the edge length (is there?). In my graph some edges would be much longer than others.

Comment: @Szabolcs I tried the MDS.m package and it does work in 8, at least their sample notebook runs fine. But, I tried it with some of my data (78 points, their example has 12 points) and it took too long (I stopped it after 30mins). So, that won't work for me.

Comment: One can utilize R's MDS algorithms in Mathematica through [RLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/guide/RLink.html).

Comment: There is the [ResourceFunction\["MultidimensionalScaling"\] in the Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultidimensionalScaling/).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a link to an article in [The Mathematica Journal Vol. 17](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2015/09/graphical-representation-of-proximity-measures-for-multidimensional-data/), with worked out examples and code:

Better late than never!

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to adapt the code in the [Multidimensional Scaling](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MultidimensionalScaling/) demonstration in the Wolfram Demonstrations project.

Comment: I saw that but, I'm not sure that it works. I tried  distances2points[{{0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}}] and the resulting points do not form an equilateral triangle, as I was expecting.