# Support for Multidimensional Scaling (MDS) in V10.4+?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, probability-or-statistics

This question was asked 4 years ago ([Support for Multidimensional Scaling (MDS)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6939/36788)), but Mathematica's statistical capability has been transformed since.

What I would like to do is take a matrix of distances between points and find an embedding in a space of a specified dimension (1, 2 or 3, typically for easy visualisation).

Is MDS functionality now built in to Mathematica?

Comment: "This question was asked" - so the how is your question different?  If you want new attention to an old question, especially one without an accepted answer, one way to do that is to place a bounty on said older question.

Comment: There is [this recent TMJ article](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2015/09/graphical-representation-of-proximity-measures-for-multidimensional-data/). Among other things it has, in section 7.2, an implementation in a few lines using the singular values decomposition (SVD). And section 5.3 has another fairly straigntforward MDS implementation, using `Eigensystem`.